# htaccess speaking url - load php file by specific keywords in url AND keep origin url AND get last parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, keyword

I need three things in the htaccess file:

1. Load a php file, if specific keywords are in the url
2. Pass the last word (after slash) of url to php as a parameter
3. Keep the origin URL in browser adress bar

e.g.

https://example.com/anyString/anyKeyword1/anyKeyword2/anyString/volvo

Or more specific examples with the keywords 'repaircars' and 'offering':

https://example.com/testsystem/repaircars/offering/volvo

https://example.com/repaircars/offering/volvo

So, whenever the keywords 'repaircars' and 'offering' are in the url, the htaccess file should load a file named

***'show.php'***

For this, I wrote the in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^repaircars/[^/]*(offering)[^/]*/ https://example.com/testsystem/show.php [L,R=301]
```

This is working fine. It's loading the show.php, if the keywords 'repaircars' and 'offering' are in the url.

But:

- How can the file show.php receive the word after the last slash in url (here the last word is: volvo) as parameter?
- How to keep the origin url in browser address bar and anyway processing the file show.php ?

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a completely different approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} repaircars
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} offering
RewriteRule /(\w+)$ /show.php?brand=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hi. Your answer is working nearly 100%. Thank you very much for this! You are a hero for me.
The only thing I'm missing: How to keep the origin url in browser adress bar after calling the file show.php
With your solution I got the url: 
https://example.com/testsystem/show.php?brand=volvo
Yes. It's logic. I know.
But it is possible to keep the origin URL https://example.com/repaircars/offering/volvo after calling show.php or would it be better to do a JavaScript Trick an overwrite the adress bar. I don't know, if Google SEO results are making trouble with such JavaScript Tricks.

Comment: Sorry, no, the solution posted above certainly does _not_ alter the URL shown in the browser. If that is the case then it is either a cached result you are looking at or some application logic (probably inside your php scripts) responsible for that.